# Firebase cloud functions - no logging?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm building a Firebase cloud function in JavaScipt that's triggered when a message is published to Pub/Sub. I've followed the [tutorial here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/pubsub-events). But it's as if the function is never called.  No logs show other than the successful deployment of the function.

Even a simple background cloud function like this won't print its logs...

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.myFunction = functions.pubsub.topic('environmental-sensors').onPublish((message, context) => {
    console.log('The function was triggered at ', context.timestamp);
    console.log('The unique ID for the event is', context.eventId);
});
```

To deploy, I run `firebase deploy --only functions`

To publish a message to Pub/Sub, I run `gcloud pubsub topics publish environmental-sensors --message="sensor data ready" --attribute="sensorName=sensor-001,temparature=75,humidity=100"`

In Pub/Sub, I'm able to view the published message, so that works fine.

And the only log message I get when running `firebase functions:log` is

```
2021-06-24T06:40:49.409447Z N myFunction:
```

What am I missing to write logs or to get the function to be called when a Pubsub message is published?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: Your function should work. Where are you looking at the logs? (Note that for the final version of the CF you need to return a Promise when all the async work is completed)

Comment: I have reproduced this on my side and this using your exact code and commands and its working fine. One thing I suggest to ensure to check if Cloud SDK has properly setup default project (`gcloud config list`) as only possible reason I can see is posting massage to different project. You can use `--project` flag as well.

Comment: `gcloud config list` shows that my intended project is the active one. I really dont know why I can't see logs. I've built another cloud function for the similar PubSub producers and they work. But when I use Firestore cloud functions, I can't see a thing

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I'm using the command line `firebase functions:log` and not seeing any

Comment: It works! I created a new Firebase project and the only thing I did differently this time was enable Google Analytics.  That one change allows logging!  Thanks for your help @vitooh and Renaud :)